# Why my code worked yesterday but not now i have not made any difference in code in vscode in python

Tags: python, tkinter

Yesterday This Code Works Fine But when i run this code today It Gives Following Error
I am absolute beginner
Easy Answers or Solutions are much Appriciated

When save_file.configure('-topmost', True) is # Commented

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bhavesh Bansiwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Bhavesh Bansiwal\Desktop\Class 11 Projects\VS Code\Story Saver\Story Maker.pyw", line 69, in save_func
    save_file.attributes(bg='white')
TypeError: wm_attributes() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bg'
```

And This Error When
save_file.configure('-topmost', True) is not Commented

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bhavesh Bansiwal\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1892, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:\Users\Bhavesh Bansiwal\Desktop\Class 11 Projects\VS Code\Story Saver\Story Maker.pyw", line 67, in save_func
    save_file.configure("-topmost", True)
TypeError: configure() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Code which Gives The Error -

```
def save_func():
    global file_path
    txt = text.get('1.0', END)
    if 'file_path' in globals():
        save_file = Tk()
        save_file.title('Save')
        save_file.geometry('200x80')
        save_file.resizable(False, False)
        save_file.configure("-topmost", True)
        save_file.eval('tk::PlaceWindow . center')
        save_file.attributes(bg='white')

        def yes_func():
            global save_perm
            save_perm = 'yes'
            save_file.destroy()
            text_file = open(file_path, "w+")
            text_file.write(txt)
            text_file.close()


        def no_func():
            global save_perm
            save_perm = ''
            save_file.destroy()

        save_text = Label(save_file, text='Do You Want to Save File', font=('consolas', 10, 'normal'), bg='white')
        save_text.place(x=10, y=5)

        save_yes = Button(save_file, text='Yes', font=('consolas', 10, 'normal'),bg='white', command=yes_func, width=8)
        save_yes.place(x=20, y=40)

        save_no = Button(save_file, text='No', font=('consolas', 10, 'normal'), bg='white', command=no_func, width=8)
        save_no.place(x=110, y=40)

        save_file.mainloop()
```

Comment: I got different error: `TypeError: configure() takes from 1 to 2 positional arguments but 3 were given` on the line `save_file.configure("-topmost", True)`.  Actually it should be `save_file.attributes("-topmost", True)` and `save_file.configure(bg="white")` instead.

Comment: What do you expect to happen with `configure("-topmost", True)`, it should be `attributes("-topmost", True)`. It seemed like you switched the arguments and understanding of `configure()` and `attributes()` method.